# Excel Populate table with continuus values

Tags: excel-formula, cell, repeat

In MS Excel I have one table with few values (i.e. 3, no fix length) and in second table these values has to be repeated lot of time (i.e. 7 times). I do not understand how to provide this with normal Excel formulas/functions.

Table 1:
A
B
C
Table 2 (target table):
A
B
C
A
B
C
A

Comment: I was thinking something like getting the information of cell row and then MOD or something like that and then use this info for Cell function

Comment: I am trying something like this but it does not work: =INDEKS(Table1!A$1:A$100; 1; MOD(ROW();COUNTA(Table1!A$1:A$100))+1)

Answer (score 0):

how stupid am I. Is used wrong name of function index: the correct is 
  =INDEX(Table1!A$1:A$100; 1; MOD(ROW();COUNTA(Table1!A$1:A$100))+1) 
and this is added in each row of table 2